# What's the impact of "Server is not responding. Connection timed out." error in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

My simulation model has agents roaming in GIS space. I built a parameter variation experiment to generate replications. I received four notices during runtime stating that "Server is not responding. Connection timed out." However, the simulation kept running and it still generated results. What is the impact of this error? Why is it occurring?

My routes are requested from the open source maps server and the routing server option is AnyLogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the model cannot get to the server, agents take straight routes by default, unless there is a cached route found (generated from a prior server request).

The GIS map object lets you specify if you want to crash the model instead, also see the help for this, it is your best friend:

[image]